# Understanding flow of recursion in calculating powersets

Tags: java

I have found a code which is calculating powersets of an array .

I am not able to understand what is happening inside the `subseq()` method.
As per my understanding and what I could see while debugging -

```
1. first [] is added.
2. Goes inside loop , `i=0` adds `[1]`
3. recursive call , `i=1` adds `[1,2]`
4. recursive call , `i=2` adds `[1,2,3]`
```

When `i =3`, it should not go inside the loop itself,
How come after this, the execution is going to `remove`.
Could you help me understand this.

```
public class printSubSequences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {1,2,3};
        List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
        subseq(0, num, new ArrayList<Integer>(), subsets );

        System.out.println(subsets);

    }

    public static void subseq(int index, int[] num, List<Integer> current, List<List<Integer>> subsets) {

        subsets.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
        for(int i = index ; i< num.length; i++) {
            current.add(num[i]);
            subseq(i+1, num, current, subsets);
            current.remove(current.size() -1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: if you dont understand what your code is doing ... the very first step is to add print statements. Have your code show you what it is doing!

Comment: ...or use a debugger (but I'm _not_ saying it's _better_ to use a debugger)

Comment: Also note that you might want to accept an answer here. When your problem is solved, take the time to accept the most helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.

When recursion hits the bottom:

```
subseq(0, {1,2,3}, [], []);
    subseq(1, {1,2,3}, [1], [[]]);
        subseq(2, {1,2,3}, [1,2], [[], [1]]);
            subseq(3, {1,2,3}, [1,2,3], [[], [1], [1,2]]); <---
```

the `for` loop is skipped in this frame, because `i == num.length`; so, the code returns to the previous frame, where `i` was `2`, and the line immediately after the `subseq(...)` is being executed:

```
current.remove(current.size() -1);
```

At this point `current = [1,2,3]`, so the last element `3` will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple funda of Java is, it will execute each and every line one after another. It will store method call in thread's stack memory.

For your example,

> 1. first [] is added.
> 2. Goes inside a loop, `i=0` adds `[1]`
> 3. recursive call

It will call subseq() and adds the call in thread's stack, but please note **current.remove(current.size() -1)** is still pending. For our understanding give this call alias A , `i=1` adds `[1,2]`, thread stack `[A]`

> 4. recursive call

same way as exalian above it will call subseq() again and adds it in method stack. Lets give this call alias B, `i=2` adds `[1,2,3]`, thread stack `[B,A]`

> 5. Jump back to the previous call

Now, for the third-time condition will going to fail. So it will skip the loop. Now, the pointer will go back to the previous calls which are pending. So, it will look into the stack `[B,A]` and go to the call B. It will start executing operations which are thereafter the recursion method call and then it will remove that from the stack. For us after performing remove operation stack would be like `[A]` removes `3`

> 6. Jump back to the previous call

The same way it will do for operation `A` and removes `2`

> 7. Jump back to the original call

It will remove `1`

**Please note**, the operation alias that I have mentions its totally for our understaing of concept. They are actually named as a method name. You can learn more about recursion on [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java).